# I cannot see wiremesh in editmode

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, wireframe

I have a problem. When I go to edit mode (a cube with subdivison surface modifier), then I switch the wireframe display, there is no edges, I cannot see the object and the mesh properly. I tried the optimal display already !

UPDATE:
I am a beginner, that's why it is difficult for me to express myself in blender language, but I will try to do my best.
My problem is: I have a cube, I put a subdivison surface modifier on it. When I wanna edit it in EDIT MODE, I switch to wireframe diplay but it doesn't work. Firstly I saw just some edges without finishing the cube, then I switched on the triangle button next to the subdivison surface name, and it shows the end of the cube aswell, but it feels like a half solution for my problem. Maybe it's not a big problem, but it's really bothering me.
I took some screenshots with description, it might helps.

My computer is a Macbook Pro M1 2021 16 inch. ( MK183MG/A ) If it helps to solve the problem. It has Macos Ventura now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate and has been asked before by someone else (similar one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/259231/107598) -- You have enabled the modifiers in *Edit* mode. That's the 2nd icon right next to their name (the square with the dots). If this is active then you will see 2 versions of the mesh at the same time. It's the base mesh that you can edit and that you have selected in your screenshot. And there is the modified mesh. This is the inner rounded black mesh. You can turn this off or enable the first icon "On Cage" and then you see only the modified mesh.

Comment: Similar problem, same tutorial: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254811/107598

Comment: I've seen you still have the problem and asked for help in one of the linked questions. If the links didn't help you then you can edit this question, add updates and details and it can be reopened. But you need to tell us what exactly does not work for you.

Comment: @Blunder alright, so that means it's not because of my computer, its a problem with the blender now and it might will be oké after an update. Thank you for your help ! I have been looking for the cause of the problem since a week now.. I will accept it and hope the best for later. !

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see what you mean. In Blender 3.4 the [X] *Optimized Display* option of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier has no effect in *Edit* mode, only in *Object* mode it shows the additional edges (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxT67.gif). -- But in Blender 2.93.6, this option has an effect in the *Edit* mode and shows in both modes the extra edges that the modifier adds (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WveX.gif). This could be a bug.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's not your computer, it's the Blender version for sure. I've added 2 images to my previous (re-posted) comment for illustration.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, oké, I will continue to work with this problem for now.

Comment: Reopened.. the problem has been addressed in the commentary? If either you or @Blunder could make an answer out of this, that would tie it up.

Comment: Yes, I know what causes the problem now.

Comment: Maybe this bug came with the *GPU Subdivision* feature. If you enabled this feature in the user preferences - *Edit > Preferences > Viewport (tab) > Subdivision (section) > [X] GPU Subdivision* - then it works as expected. The *Subsurface Division* modifier must be at the bottom of the stack.